# I want to add specific word on Title bar how to do this

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to add "Buy" word in Just Title tab not in post Title Which show in image 
how can do this can some one help on it??
[image: I want to add Buy word in before title]
[image: Not here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try Yoast plugin to customize meta title, description etc -

[image: Here is the screenshot]